# T-SQL to find rows with given number of digits

Tags: t-sql

I need to select rows where a column (that is varchar) contains 10 or more digits (any) in a row.

```
'115555711111' - true
'abc11143555111111def' - true
'000345345500abc' - true

'1411a6551a111' - false
```

This does not work:
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]{10}%', Column1) > 0

Comment: All of your successful examples show 10 or more of *the same* digit. Is that part of the requirements?

Comment: No, that was only example. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%' + REPLICATE('[0-9]',10) + '%'
```